# Can I leave SSD unsecured?

Tags: ssd, desktop-computer

I just bought a Samsung SSD 830 series for my desktop, but forget to buy a mount for it. Is it ok if I leave it connected, but not screwed in? Do I have to worry about short circuiting or any other dangers? The computer stays put in one place and is never touched nor moved around.

Thanks for your input...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It shouldn't be conductive, but if it slides in to the wrong spot who knows what could happen, might block a fan or something. Also I suppose the metal clips on the SATA cables could be conductive and could cause a short. Then there's the potential for physical damage if the computer ever gets moved and the SSD falls on a board or component.

That being said mine has been floating around the case for a year with no damage (yet).

Comment: living on the edge!

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but I have similar situation and here is my mounting solution.

Inside my computer case's right side (so under the mobo tray) i zip stripped mine to the cut outs in my 5 1/4 in bays. The case manufacturer for my case simply "Punch and push" tabs to hold the 5 1/4" accesories (DVD, fan controler and so on). I wove a few zip strips in these openings and clampped my SSD to them. The cover slides back on and now, no loose SSD in my case.

Just figured I would pass on a solution to a no brackets situation.

Comment: That's one of the awesome things about SSD's: they can take a little abuse. With no moving parts and no significant heat, the only concern is physically securing the device. You could even _duct tape_ it if need be.

Comment: or velcro whould even do the trick. Some ssd cases my be conductive, aluminum. I don't like loose things in my case so the zip strips worked for me.